# Why Nuxt generate publicPath does not work as expected at first visit?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, nuxt.config.js

I'm using Nuxt v2.15.8 to create a static website using `nuxt generate` command. I expect the requests to the server for fetching the main js and CSS files to be made to `/` path, as I specified in my nuxt.cofig:

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
  // ...
  build: {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/_nuxt/' : '/',
  },
  // ...
}
```

When I visit the generated static website, despite what I specified in the build config, at first it tries to load data from `/_nuxt/` path which does not exist. As you can see in the attached pictures, after getting a 404 error for this route, it loads data successfully from the correct path which is `/`, but it should not send those requests to `/_nuxt` path to begin with.

**Request to the wrong path**
[image]

**Request to the correct path**
[image]

Any idea about how can I eliminate those initial requests to `/_nuxt/`?

Comment: Hm, I never faced this issue before. What kind of data are you trying to load here? Also, what happens if you `yarn generate && yarn start` the project, is it still buggy with an untouched `publicPath`?

Comment: @kissu I'm trying to load the main css and js files generated by nuxt when I run `yarn generate` command. The result is the same if I `yarn generate && yarn start` the project. And when publicPath is untouched, these js and css files are placed inside **_nuxt** directory, which I do not want.

Comment: What do you want to do with those files **after** the build? Seems quite a strange usage overall.

Comment: I just use the files generated in the 'dist' directory and place them on my servers root directory

Comment: You should use git for that. And I'm not sure why this wouldn't work tbh. Why the need to change the path?

Comment: My client insist on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue by adding the following lines to nuxt.config.js:

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
  // ...
  build: {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/_nuxt/' : '/',
  },
  // added the following lines
  hooks: {
    render: {
      resourcesLoaded(resources) {
        const path = `/`
        resources.clientManifest && (resources.clientManifest.publicPath = path)
        resources.modernManifest && (resources.modernManifest.publicPath = path)
        resources.serverManifest && (resources.serverManifest.publicPath = path)
      }
    }
  },
  // ...

}
```